# Nested repeaters databind in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have two nested repeaters and I want call  repeater2 databind inside repeater1.
Why? Well, I need Repeat some lines of repeater2. But I try this and repeater2 only work 1 time, should work 4 times. Please Help!

Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound

```
    For i = 0 To 4
        con.Open()
        Dim consulta As String = "SELECT DISTINCT Ordenes.Orden, Ordenes.Id, Ordenes.Codigo, Ordenes.Descripcion, Ordenes.Cantidad, Ordenes.PrecioVenta, " & _
        "Ordenes.FechaCreacion, Inventario.CostoUnitario, Inventario.Marca, Inventario.Garantia, Inventario.Modelo, Inventario.Color, Inventario.Serial, " & _
        "Inventario.CodigoFabricante, Clientes.Nombres, Clientes.Apellidos, Inv_Imagenes.Enlace FROM Ordenes INNER JOIN Inventario ON Ordenes.Codigo = " & _
        "Inventario.Codigo INNER JOIN Clientes ON Ordenes.IdCliente = Clientes.IdCliente INNER JOIN Inv_Imagenes ON Ordenes.Codigo = Inv_Imagenes.Item WHERE " & _
        "(Ordenes.id = @idt) AND (Inv_Imagenes.Tipo = 'img') AND (Inv_Imagenes.Orden = 1)"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(consulta, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idt", e.Item.DataItem("id").ToString)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim Repeater2 As Repeater = e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2")
        Repeater2.DataSource = dr
        Repeater2.DataBind()
        dr.Close()
        con.Close()
    Next

End Sub
```

Well example, someone orders one 4 phones, I need render 4 lines to entry the Imei of everyone phone one by one to insert in other table

Comment: Juan why you want iterate 4 times ??

Comment: Yes, why do you need to rebind Repeater2 to the same data four times?

Answer (score 0):

You can test with e.Item.ItemIndex

```
If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or _
            (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then

            //Treat with e.Item.ItemIndex


 End If
```

Comment: Well example, someone orders one 4 phones, I need render 4 lines to entry the Imei of everyone phone one by one to insert in other table